# fuzzywuzzy returning single characters, not strings

Tags: python, list, return-value, arcgis, fuzzywuzzy

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here and why my data is returning wrong. Writing this code to use fuzzywuzzy to clean bad input road names against a list of correct names, replacing the incorrect with the closest match.

It's returning all lines of `data2` back. I'm looking for it to return the same, or replaced lines of `data1` back to me.

**My Minimal, Reproducible Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
import usaddress
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

data1 =('3176 DETRIT ROAD')
data2 =('DETROIT RD')

try:
    data1 = usaddress.tag(data1)
except usaddress.RepeatedLabelError:
    pass

roaddnum2 = data1[0].get('AddressNumber', '')
roadir2 = data1[0].get('StreetNamePreDirectional', '')
roadname2 = data1[0].get('StreetName', '')
roaddsg2 = data1[0].get('StreetNamePostType', '')

street2 = (roadir2, roadname2, roaddsg2)
street2 = " ".join(street2)
street2 = street2.strip()
data2 = data2.split(',')

if street2 not in data2:
    street2 = process.extract(street2, data2)
    print(street2[0])
```

**My full code**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
import usaddress
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

def convert_tolist(string):
    li = list(string.split(" "))
    return li

with open(r"Cass_Howard - Copy.csv") as csv_file,\
        open("Final_Test_Clean.csv", "w") as f,\
        open(r"TEST_no_dups12.csv") as ul:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    file_1 = csv_file
    file_2 = ul

    for data1, data2 in zip(file_1, file_2):
        data1 = data1.split(',')
        data1 = data1[18]
        data1 = data1.upper()
        data2 = data2.strip()
        data2 = data2.split(',')
        data2 = ''.join(data2)
        try:
            data1 = usaddress.tag(data1)
        except usaddress.RepeatedLabelError:
            pass

        roaddnum2 = data1[0].get('AddressNumber', '')
        roadir2 = data1[0].get('StreetNamePreDirectional', '')
        roadname2 = data1[0].get('StreetName', '')
        roaddsg2 = data1[0].get('StreetNamePostType', '')

        street2 = (roadir2, roadname2, roaddsg2)
        street2 = " ".join(street2)
        street2 = street2.strip()
        data1 = list(data1)
        convert_tolist(data2)


        if street2 not in data2:
            street2 = process.extract(street2, data2)
            print(street2)
```

`street2` query data(around 950 lines)

```
DETROIT ROAD
DETROIT ROAD
MANNIX ST
MANNIX ST
```

`data2` choices data(around 200 lines)

```
ACRES
ADERSON RD
AIRPORT RD
ALGONQUIN
```

Comment: You need to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code doesn't seem to be actually using `fuzz`. Also, what is the purpose of the `convert_tolist` function? It is longer to call that than just `.split(" ")`.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I added the Minimal, Reproducible Example to the top of the post and will take your other comments into account when revising.

Comment: Some more suggestions: `fuzz` seems unused. Overwriting `data1` only when `usaddress.tag()` doesn't fail is questionable. What is the outcome of this? What are the results in `roaddnum2`, `roadir2` etc? Can you hardcode those instead of using `usaddress.tag()`? What happens in the last `if ...` clause, which path does it take?

Comment: this is the outcome from `usaddress.tag()` `(OrderedDict([('AddressNumber', '3176'), ('StreetName', 'DETROIT'), ('StreetNamePostType', 'ROAD')]), 'Street Address')` and `roadnum2'` would call `3176` and `roaddir2` would call a cardinal direction if there was one and so on. I can't hardcode these because some addresses have a cardinal direction and some don't, some have DR left off the end and some don't. `usadress.tag()` is smart enough to parse the address into the proper category  and allows me to work with nasty user input address easier.

Comment: Okay, I'm halfway there. fuzzywuzzy requires you to pass an iterable so I had to add `data2 = data2.split(',')` to get the full strings to return. But now it's clear that I'm returning the exact lines from `data2`. I'll update my Minimal, reproduceable example to reflect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue here was fuzzywuzzy requires you to pass an iterable so I had to add `data2 = data2.split(',')` to get the full strings to return.

My other issue was thinking I needed to use `zip()` to compare my files when `zip()` is for comparing parallel and not cross products.

Here is what I came up with that works. There is no issue with the code but fuzzywuzzy is not accurate enough for this tool to be practical to clean my data with the amount of typos in my address data.

If you can think of a way for me to clean up the if/else statement i'd be willing to hear it.

```
import os
import csv
import shutil
import usaddress
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process

with open(r"TEST_Cass_Howard.csv") as csv_file, \
        open(".\Scratch\Final_Test_Clean.csv", "w") as f, \
        open(r"TEST_Unique_List.csv") as ul:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)
    csv_reader1 = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    correct = list(ul)
    for line in csv_reader:
        line = line[18]
        line = line.upper()
        if line == '' or line == ' ':
            line = ''
        else:
            try:
                addressbrk = usaddress.tag(line)
            except usaddress.RepeatedLabelError:
                addressbrk = line
            line = addressbrk  # alt output: ('Please fix the incorect format of: %s,' % addressbrk)
        if line != '':
            roadnum2 = line[0].get('AddressNumber', '')
            roadir2 = line[0].get('StreetNamePreDirectional', '')
            roadname2 = line[0].get('StreetName', '')
            roaddsg2 = line[0].get('StreetNamePostType', '')
        else:
            line = ''
        if line != '':
            street2 = (roadir2, roadname2, roaddsg2)
            street2 = " ".join(street2)
            street2 = street2.strip()
        else:
            street2 = ''
        if street2 != '':
            if street2 not in correct:
                street2 = process.extractOne(street2, correct)
            else:
                street2 = '\n'
        if street2 != '':
            tgthr = (roadnum2, street2[0])
        else:
            tgthr = ''
        if tgthr != '':
            final = (' '.join(tgthr))
        else:
            final = ('Null' + '\n')
        f.writelines(final)
original = r"TEST_Cass_Howard.csv" 
target = (r'.\Scratch\Cass_Howard_Clean.csv')
shutil.copyfile(original, target)
df1 = pd.read_csv('.\Scratch\Final_Test_Clean.csv', header=None)
df1.columns = ["WELL_ADDR_CLN"]
df = pd.read_csv('.\Scratch\Cass_Howard_Clean.csv')
df = df.join(df1)
new_data = df['WELL_ADDR_CLN']
df = df.drop(columns=['WELL_ADDR_CLN'])
df.insert(loc=19, column='WELL_ADDR_CLN', value=new_data)
os.remove(".\Scratch\Cass_Howard_Clean.csv")
df.to_csv("Cass_Howard_Clean.csv", index=False)
os.remove('.\Scratch\Final_Test_Clean.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not certain I've fully understood your issue, but modifying your reprex, I have produced the following solution.

```py
import usaddress
from fuzzywuzzy import process

data1 = "3176 DETRIT ROAD"
choices = ["DETROIT RD"]

try:
    data1 = usaddress.tag(data1)
except usaddress.RepeatedLabelError:
    pass

parts = [
    data1[0].get("StreetNamePreDirectional"),
    data1[0].get("StreetName"),
    data1[0].get("StreetNamePostType"),
]

street = " ".join([x for x in parts if x])

if street not in choices:
    street = " ".join(
        [data1[0].get("AddressNumber"), process.extract(street, choices)[0][0]]
    )

print(street)
```

This yields:

```
3176 DETROIT RD
```

So basically, it has replaces the street name bits with the best match from the choices list using the `process.extract()` function.

---

And here it is as a callable function:

```py
import usaddress
from fuzzywuzzy import process


def best_street(addr: str, choices: list[str]) -> str:
    try:
        usaddr = usaddress.tag(addr)
    except usaddress.RepeatedLabelError:
        pass
    street_parts = [
        usaddr[0].get("StreetNamePreDirectional"),
        usaddr[0].get("StreetName"),
        usaddr[0].get("StreetNamePostType"),
    ]
    street = " ".join([x for x in street_parts if x])
    return " ".join(
        [usaddr[0].get("AddressNumber"), process.extract(street, choices)[0][0]]
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    choices = ["AIRPORT RD", "DETROIT RD"]
    print(best_street("123 Detrt", choices))
    print(best_street("9876 AIRPUMP DR", choices))
```

yielding:

```
123 DETROIT RD
9876 AIRPORT RD
```